# Why does Agda reduce my function application for some arguments but not for others?

Tags: agda

I am playing with `joinˡ⁺` from the standard library's AVL tree implementation. This function is defined with six pattern matching clauses. When I apply the function to an argument, then Agda does or doesn't reduce my function application expression, depending on which of the six clauses matches my argument. (Or so it seems to me.)

Here's code that applies the function to an argument that matches the function's first clause. It's the left-hand side of the equality in the goal. Agda reduces it to the right-hand side and I can finish the proof with `refl`. So this one works as expected.

(Note that the code uses version 1.3 of the standard library. It seems that more recent versions moved the AVL tree code from `Data.AVL` to `Data.Tree.AVL`.)

```
module Repro2 where

open import Data.Nat using (ℕ ; suc)
open import Data.Nat.Properties using (<-strictTotalOrder)
open import Data.Product using (_,_)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_ ; refl)

open import Data.AVL.Indexed <-strictTotalOrder

okay :
  ∀ {l u h} k₆ k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) k₄ t₃ t₅ t₇ b →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {suc (suc h)} {suc h} {suc (suc h)}
    k₆ (1# , node k₂ t₁ (node {hˡ = h} {suc h} {suc h} k₄ t₃ t₅ b) ∼+) t₇ ∼-
  ≡
  (0# , node k₄ (node k₂ t₁ t₃ (max∼ b)) (node k₆ t₅ t₇ (∼max b)) ∼0)

okay k₆ k₂ t₁ k₄ t₃ t₅ t₇ b = refl
```

The next example targets the second clause of the function definition. Unlike above, the goal does not reduce at all this time, i.e., the `joinˡ⁺` doesn't go away.

```
not-okay : ∀ {l u h} k₄ k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _)  t₃ t₅ →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {suc h} {h} {suc h}
    k₄ (1# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼-) t₅ ∼-
    ≡
    (0# , node k₂ t₁ (node k₄ t₃ t₅ ∼0) ∼0)

not-okay k₄ k₂ t₁ t₃ t₅ = {!!}
```

What am I missing?

**Addition after MrO's answer**

MrO nailed it. What I knew was that if a clause pattern-matches a subterm of an argument (or the whole argument), then I obviously need to pass a matching data constructor for that subterm to make the evaluator pick that clause. However, that's not enough. As MrO pointed out, in some cases I also need to pass data constructors for subterms that *other* clauses (i.e., not just the clause I'm going for) pattern-match, even though the clause at hand doesn't care about them.

To explore this (to me: major new) insight, I tried out the remaining four clauses of `joinˡ⁺`. The last clause, clause #6, led to another insight.

Here's clause #3. It works pretty much the same as `not-okay`.

```
clause₃ : ∀ {l u h} k₄ k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) t₃ t₅ →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {suc h} {h} {suc h}
    k₄ (1# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼0) t₅ ∼-
  ≡
  (1# , node k₂ t₁ (node k₄ t₃ t₅ ∼-) ∼+)

-- This does not work:
--   clause₃ k₄ k₂ t₁ t₃ t₅ = {!!} 

clause₃ k₄ k₂ t₁ (node k t₃ t₄ bal) t₅ = refl
```

Clause #4 is more involved.

```
clause₄ : ∀ {l u h} k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) t₃ →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {h} {h} {h}
    k₂ (1# , t₁) t₃ ∼0
  ≡
  (1# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼-)

-- This does not work:
--   clause₄ k₂ t₁ t₃ = {!!}

-- This still doesn't, because of t' (or so I thought):
--   clause₄ k₂ (node k t t′ b) t₃ = {!!}

-- Surprise! This still doesn't, because of b:
--   clause₄ k₂ (node k t (leaf l<u) b) t₃ = {!!}
--   clause₄ k₂ (node k t (node k′ t′′ t′′′ b') b) t₃ = {!!}

clause₄ k₂ (node k t (leaf l<u) ∼0) t₃ = refl
clause₄ k₂ (node k t (leaf l<u) ∼-) t₃ = refl

clause₄ k₂ (node k t (node k′ t′′ t′′′ b') ∼+) t₃ = refl
clause₄ k₂ (node k t (node k′ t′′ t′′′ b') ∼0) t₃ = refl
clause₄ k₂ (node k t (node k′ t′′ t′′′ b') ∼-) t₃ = refl
```

Clause #5 is analogous to clause #4.

```
clause₅ : ∀ {l u h} k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) t₃ →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {h} {suc h} {suc h}
    k₂ (1# , t₁) t₃ ∼+
  ≡
  (0# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼0)

clause₅ k₂ (node k t (leaf l<u) ∼0) t₃ = refl
clause₅ k₂ (node k t (leaf l<u) ∼-) t₃ = refl

clause₅ k₂ (node k t (node k′ t'′ t′′′ b′) ∼+) t₃ = refl
clause₅ k₂ (node k t (node k′ t'′ t′′′ b′) ∼0) t₃ = refl
clause₅ k₂ (node k t (node k′ t'′ t′′′ b′) ∼-) t₃ = refl
```

Clause #6 was a bit of a surprise to me. I thought that I needed to pass data constructors wherever any of the clauses required them. But that's not what MrO said. And it shows in this clause:

```
clause₆ : ∀ {l u h} k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) t₃ b →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {h} {h} {h}
    k₂ (0# , t₁) t₃ b
  ≡
  (0# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ b)


clause₆ k₂ t₁ t₃ b = refl
```

Easier than I thought: no additional data constructors required. Why? I went to read the pattern matching part of the Agda reference:

https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/function-definitions.html#case-trees

I had read it before, but had completely failed to apply what it says. Agda finds the clause to be picked by way of a decision tree, a *case tree*. To me, it now looks like Agda needs data constructors as long as it hasn't reached a leaf of the case tree, i.e., as long as it hasn't figured out which clause to pick.

For the function at hand, the case tree seems to start with the question: `0#` or `1#`? At least that would explain clause #6:

- If it's `0#` then we know that it must be clause #6, no more data constructors required. Clause #6 is the only match for `0#`. So, we're at a leaf, our case tree traversal is over.
- If it's `1#` then we need to do more matching, i.e., move down in the case tree to the next level. There, we need another data constructor to look at. In total, we thus need a data constructor for each visited level of the case tree.

At least this is my current mental model, which seems to be supported by the observations made about `joinˡ⁺`.

Trying to validate this mental model a little more, I went and modified my copy of the standard library by reversing the order of the six clauses. As Agda builds the case tree by going through the clauses in order and going left to right within each clause, this should give us a much better case tree.

`0#` vs. `1#` would still be the first level of the decision tree, but it would be followed by the outer balance, followed by the inner balance. We wouldn't need to split trees into nodes, except for the now last (previously first) clause, which actually matches on that.

And, indeed, things turn out as expected. Here's what the proofs look like with the reversed order of clauses in my modified standard library.

```
clause₁′ : ∀ {l u h} k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) t₃ b →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {h} {h} {h}
    k₂ (0# , t₁) t₃ b
  ≡
  (0# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ b)

clause₁′ k₂ t₁ t₃ b = refl

clause₂′ : ∀ {l u h} k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) t₃ →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {h} {suc h} {suc h}
    k₂ (1# , t₁) t₃ ∼+
  ≡
  (0# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼0)

clause₂′ k₂ t₁ t₃ = refl

clause₃′ : ∀ {l u h} k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) t₃ →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {h} {h} {h}
    k₂ (1# , t₁) t₃ ∼0
  ≡
  (1# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼-)

clause₃′ k₂ t₁ t₃ = refl

clause₄′ : ∀ {l u h} k₄ k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) t₃ t₅ →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {suc h} {h} {suc h}
    k₄ (1# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼0) t₅ ∼-
  ≡
  (1# , node k₂ t₁ (node k₄ t₃ t₅ ∼-) ∼+)

clause₄′ k₄ k₂ t₁ t₃ t₅ = refl

not-okay′ : ∀ {l u h} k₄ k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) t₃ t₅ →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {suc h} {h} {suc h}
    k₄ (1# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼-) t₅ ∼-
    ≡
    (0# , node k₂ t₁ (node k₄ t₃ t₅ ∼0) ∼0)

not-okay′ k₄ k₂ t₁ t₃ t₅ = refl

okay′ :
  ∀ {l u h} k₆ k₂ (t₁ : Tree (const ℕ) _ _ _) k₄ t₃ t₅ t₇ b →
  joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {suc (suc h)} {suc h} {suc (suc h)}
    k₆ (1# , node k₂ t₁ (node {hˡ = h} {suc h} {suc h} k₄ t₃ t₅ b) ∼+) t₇ ∼-
  ≡
  (0# , node k₄ (node k₂ t₁ t₃ (max∼ b)) (node k₆ t₅ t₇ (∼max b)) ∼0)

okay′ k₆ k₂ t₁ k₄ t₃ t₅ t₇ b = refl
```

Comment: If you want an explanation of how Agda translates definitions by pattern matching to a case tree with all the gritty details, I'd recommend our JFP paper from January: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming/article/elaborating-dependent-copattern-matching-no-pattern-left-behind/F13CECDAB2B6200135D45452CA44A8B3 (open access).

Comment: Oh, great! An authoritative answer right from the source! Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for Agda to be able to reduce your expression you need to pattern match on  `t₃`

```
not-okay _ _ _ (leaf _) _ = refl
not-okay _ _ _ (node _ _ _ _) _ = refl
```

My understanding as to why this is needed is the following: `joinˡ⁺` is defined inductively on five parameters. In every case, you need to specify all of these parameters for Agda to reduce the expression (by this, I mean that Agda needs to know, for all these 5 parameters, which constructors are currently given).

In your `not-okay` function, you consider the quantity `joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {suc h} {h} {suc h} k₄ (1# , node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼-) t₅ ∼-` in which case four of the five parameters where specified constructor-wise (`1#`, `node k₂ t₁ t₃ ∼-`, `∼-` and `∼-`), but not `t₃` which was the missing idea.

On the contrary, in your `okay` function, you consider the quantity `joinˡ⁺ {l = l} {u} {suc (suc h)} {suc h} {suc (suc h)} k₆ (1# , node k₂ t₁ (node {hˡ = h} {suc h} {suc h} k₄ t₃ t₅ b) ∼+) t₇ ∼-` where all five of these elements were already specified.

Comment: Thank you so much! Never in a million years would this have occurred to me. I had been banging my head against this issue for two days. I explored your answer a little more by working through the remaining four clauses of the AVL tree function in question. I'll add my results to the question to illustrate your point with a few more examples, which might help others.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. And thanks for your thorough follow up which gives interesting insight as to how Agda handles such cases.